# nodejs sequelize map response

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an API that should return an array, good but my result each array has more than 3 objects so I need to map them and I did it doing it in the back end

```
async function getAllProduct(req,res) {
        try {
            const results = await Products.findAll({
                // raw: true, <= remove
                attributes:['id','name', 'float', 'price'],
                include: [{
                    model: SubCategory,
                    as: 'subcategory',
                    attributes: ['id','name'],
                },
                {
                    model:Exteriors,
                    as: 'exteriors',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
                {
                    model:Types,
                    as: 'types',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
            ],
            })

            results.map( (products) => {
                const model = {
                    id: products.id,
                    name: products.name,
                    float: products.float,
                    price: products.price,
                    id_sub: products.subcategory.id,
                    subcategory: products.subcategory.name,
                    id_types: products.types.id,
                    type: products.types.name,
                    id_ext: products.exteriors.id,
                    exterior: products.exteriors.name,
                }
                listProducts.push(model);
            })
            if(listProducts){
              return res.status(200).json({listProducts})
            }
            else{
              return res.status(400).json({result: 'failed to get Products'})
            }
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error);
         }
}
```

it would be better to map the result to the front end or already send mapped, and how could I narrow down this path to fetch the data from the front

Comment: So what your question actually ? Your `results.map` is just returning or constructing the same array which was previous as `results` ?